# Using JavaScript, how might I be able to create a function that calls from a PHP file to add keys and properties to a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, discord

So I'm using Discord.JS to create a Discord Bot, and I have a command

```
 if(command === "addme") {
 //code here
 return message.reply(`Added ${message.author} to Database!`);
 };
```

how do I make it call a PHP function from a file that adds a key and a property to a JSON file?

I'm stuck on where to begin here.  I've tried solutions from other problems people have posted on this site, but I can't find anything that solved mine.

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where do you want to call your `php function`,

By the looks of it ,If I am not mistaken ... seems like you don't want to interact with `DiscordJS`'s APIs instead a `custom PHP function`?

1. Client Side

   - Is it on a browser ,iOS or Android? - There are couple of different approaches depending on the choice of environment you are in.
2. Server Side

   - I assume you are using JS as your back-end , you could use an `HTTP client` like [request](https://github.com/request/request)

simple lines like

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://saficloud.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the SafiCloud homepage.
});
```

is right where you need to begin,

Cheers :)

Comment: this is for browser, and I am using JS as back-end.  What do you mean by "don't want to interact with DiscordJS's API"?

Comment: since you wanted to call a PHP function i.e Not a method in DiscordJS's API? So you can do that using `request` , as in they can co-exist ... You can only interact with Discord's methods using it's APIs, in your case ... you want to call a custom PHP function , which is outside Node, But from Node ... Hope you understand :)